# Error parsing AWS ALB Public Key using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, openssl, jwt

I am trying to using AWS OIDC. The returned token uses ES256 for signing the JWT. openssl_verify is throwing the error:

```
error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

Sample public key returned from [AWS](https://public-keys.auth.elb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/6e6ceea1-8d11-485e-a8a2-b72dc20b6bb7):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE4eAWXhEm8pu66JIWu3KjA3OO/ymg
4PsTYB94LgTf2hU2sjKABqg01iHTh5kWSlyQ5iOwQim0FDrER5EuAt0F8A==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Any clue of the root cause of this error?

Comment: https://www.ssl247.com/kb/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting/apache/errors-asn1-encoding-routine-apache

Comment: My key is correct and has no extra spaces.